# PHP concat operator will move the content to the beginning

Tags: php

I write a PHP code snippet in WordPress, as below:

```
            <td><?php echo '<!-- 2021-09-29: Replace Font Awesome tag <i class="fas fa-cloud-download-alt"></i> with the SVG sprite, to improve performance. -->
            <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
                <use href="' . bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"/>
            </svg><a download-link="'.site_url( '/' ).$post->post_name.'-download-thanks" href="'.$link_url.'" class="download-url"> Download</a>' ?></td>
```

What I expect is that bloginfo('template_directory') will be inserted into the href, as below:

```
<td><svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
                <use href="https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"/>
            </svg><a download-link="xxx" href="xxx" class="download-url"> Download</a></td>
```

But the actual output is:

```
<td>https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme
            <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
                <use href="/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"/>
            </svg><a download-link="xxx" href="xxx" class="download-url"> Download</a></td>
```

The path generated by bloginfo('template_directory') is put before the string generated by PHP echo, why?

**Update**

Sorry for missing the information about the function [bloginfo](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/). I will try [get_bloginfo](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_bloginfo/) and update this post.

Comment: My guess is `bloginfo()` is echoing its result instead of returning it.

Comment: I agree with @Barman, there is à dedicated function to get the values : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_bloginfo/

Comment: @Philippe, thank you very much. After using get_bloginfo, the issue is solved.

Comment: Nice to read it :) Happy coding !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `bloginfo()` isn't returning anything, it's doing its own echoing. This happens before the function returns, so it gets printed before the caller concatenates the result and prints its resulting string.

Either change `bloginfo()` to return the string instead of printing it, or don't use concatenation. Print the first part, then call `bloginfo()`, then print the second part.

```
<td><?php echo '<!-- 2021-09-29: Replace Font Awesome tag <i class="fas fa-cloud-download-alt"></i> with the SVG sprite, to improve performance. -->
<svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
    <use href="';
bloginfo('template_directory');
echo '/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"/>
</svg><a download-link="'.site_url( '/' ).$post->post_name.'-download-thanks" href="'.$link_url.'" class="download-url"> Download</a>' ?></td>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Though finally I use get_bloginfo function to solve the issue, I belive your implementation also works.

Comment: Is `bloginfo()` just a function that does `echo get_bloginfo()`?

Comment: Yes, I think so, the function is provided by WordPress, and I don't know if it is possible to see the source code of the implementation. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/